# How do I click on a button on a website using selenium - python?

Tags: python, selenium

I  am trying to click on "Load More" on a page using selenium. I used the below css_selector code :

```
element= driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#amscroll-page-2]')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element)
```

I am getting the following error.

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".amscroll-load-button"}
  (Session info: chrome=83.0.4103.61)
```

and I used xpath code:

```
elemnent=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="amscroll-page-2"]')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)
time.sleep(5)
login=element.click()
```

i am getting the following error

```
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <div class="amscroll-page loading" id="amscroll-page-2" rel="2">...</div> is not clickable at point (382, 18). Other element would receive the click: <div class="naaod__content">...</div>
  (Session info: chrome=83.0.4103.61)
```

The html code of where till where i want to scroll down and click is :

```
    <div class="amscroll-page loading" id="amscroll-page-2" rel="2"><input type="button" 
class="amscroll-load-button" style="background: #2675C2;" onclick="amscroll_object.loadNextPage(2);" value="Load More"></div>
```

There is a load more button over here which i want to click on using selenium.

Comment: There is some scroll logic that requires you to scroll for the button to appear. I have a working script, however, if you read the [Terms of service](https://www.jarir.com/sa-en/terms-of-service) of the page you're scraping, you will realize that scraping is prohibited. I will therefore not provide the answer.

Answer (score 2):

To do that you should use the `click()` function from the `selenium` module. We will find the button by a `CSS selector` - this will decrease the chances that the wrong element will be clicked

```
self.webdriver.find_element_by_css_selector('input[class="amscroll-load-button"]').click()
```

However, I would recommend using that code

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

WebDriverWait(self.webdriver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input[class="amscroll-load-button"]'))).click()
```

This code checks for the button to be clickable X seconds, and if it does it will be clicked.

Comment: driver.webdriver.find_element_by_css_selector('input[c
lass="amscroll-load-button"]').click()
AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'webdr
iver'  I am getting this error.

Comment: when I use the second code I am getting this error: NameError: name 'self' is not defined

Comment: @raptorzee you have to replace the `self.webdriver` with the name of your `webdriver` instance.

Comment: no mate. now I am getting this error.raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified
  (Session info: chrome=83.0.4103.61)

Comment: @raptorzee `driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input[class="amscroll-load-button"]').click()` are you sure that you call the exact command?

Comment: raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"input[class="amscroll-load-button"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=83.0.4103.61) .. Now I get this error

Comment: @raptorzee that means the element is not on the site. Try to use the version with `WebdriverWait`

Comment: when i use the webdriverwait im getting this error.     raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException:                                                                 my code is WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input[class="amscroll-load-button"]'))).click()

Comment: Does `element_to_be_clickable` work if the element is not present in DOM yet? Perhaps `presence_of_element_located` is needed first.

Comment: @raptorzee can you link me a website and tell which exactly button do you need to click?

Comment: when I use presence_of_element_located. I get this error  [raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: ]

Comment: @raptorzee you need to use `driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html').send_keys(Keys.END)` and then `driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input[class="amscroll-load-button"]').click()`

Comment: @AleksanderIkleiw  raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <input type="button" class="amscroll-load-button" style="background: #2675C2;" onclick="amscroll_object.loadNextPage(2);" value="Load More"> is not clickable at point (382, 5).
  (Session info: chrome=83.0.4103.61)

Comment: @raptorzee ok, so: instead of `driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input[class="amscroll-load-button"]').click()`  use `driver.find_element_by_id('amscroll-page-2').click()`

Comment: ive tried this numberous times but it never works. raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted:

Comment: @raptorzee did you used the `kets.END` as the previous command? the whole code should look `driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html').send_keys(Keys.END)` then `driver.find_element_by_id('amscroll-page-2').click()`

Comment: yes mate. driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html').send_keys(Keys.END)
driver.find_element_by_id('amscroll-page-2').click()

Comment: the last method that comes to my mind is `driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html').send_keys(Keys.END)` `elem = driver.find_element_by_id('amscroll-page-2')` `driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", elem)`

Comment: this scrolls the page all the way down but doesnt click... LOL

Comment: It should scroll down 5 times already. that is usage of a `driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html').send_keys(Keys.END)`

Comment: this is take it all the way to the end

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this by using the following  code:

```
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]")
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(button).click(button).perform()
```